# Inline-block element pushing other iinline-block elements

Tags: html, css

Why inline-block elements like spans other inline-block elements push besides them, for example

```html
<span>Span 1</span>
<span>Span 2</span>
<span style="margin-top">Span 3</span>
```

will move all spans 1 and 2 where Span 3 goes?

Comment: wut? First of all: spans aren't inline-block by default; they're inline. If you want them inline-block you need to specify that. Second: style="margin-top" doesn't make sense, you forgot the value, like this: "margin-top: 20px;" but that won't work because inline elements won't work with margins. Last: I don't understand your question

Comment: Oh wait now I understand what you mean. That's just how inline-blocks work, they align on the baseline. If you want to align them on top try setting display: block; and float: left;

Comment: No, inline-blocks align along the `baseline` by default...not the bottom. The two are quite different.

Comment: @JonasGrumann Why did you add code that wasn't part of the question?

Comment: I thought this is what you actually wanted. The code before was terrible and it didn't make sense.

Comment: Jonas is correct. I was editing but he did a better job.

Comment: @JonasGrumann **Never** add code, at least not before asking the OP about their intention

Comment: @LGSon I rolled back my changes, now it doesn't make sense again. It doesn't even show the problem, but now it's how you wanted it.

Comment: You're edit was great @Jonas

Comment: @JonasGrumann No, it is not how I wanted, I wanted you to **check with the OP** before edit the question when it comes to add code ... now the OP **did** confirm that your edit was okay, so don't get it why you took it out

Comment: Yeah sorry I had to undo it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because blocks are aliigned by baseline - the bottom of typical letters:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: silver;
}

p {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Base line goes here __________
  <span>Span 1</span>
  <span>Span 2</span>
  <span>Span 3</span> _______
</p>

<p>
  Base line goes here __________
  <span>Span 1</span>
  <span>Span 2</span>
  <span style="margin-top: 1em;">Span 3</span> _______
</p>

<p>
  Base line goes here __________
  <span>Span 1</span>
  <span>Span 2</span>
  <span>Span 3<br>Span 3</span> _______
</p>
```

Comment: I upvoted, this could be the answer I just need to understand what a baseline is.

Comment: It's the imaginary line at the base of all the letters.

Comment: inline beside an inline-block element got the same baseline so it goes together? But inlines cannot have top margins so why it should move with the inline-block element with a top margin? I just added inlines beside the inline-block elements.